# how to insert date(long format) into access database using datetimepicker in c# ? (error is in date part only)

Tags: c#, ms-access, datetimepicker

[Error image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKT4k.jpg)
  the error is in query line , its shows syntax error

try 
{

```
    string zero = "0";
    DateTime dat = this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
    connection1.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = connection1;
    command.CommandText = "insert into client_table(CLIENT, DATE,BILL_AMOUNT, PAID_AMOUNT, BALANCE, CONTACT, ADDRESS )VALUES ('" + txt_client.Text + "', #" + dat.ToLongDateString() + "# ,'" + zero + "','" + zero + "','" + zero + "','" + txt_contact.Text + "','" + txt_address.Text + "')";

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection1.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("New Client Registration done Successfully.");
    connection1.Dispose();
    this.Hide();
    employee_form f1 = new employee_form("");
    f1.ShowDialog();
}
```

thank you in advance

Comment: So long as your column in the database is set as a DateTime type; It won't be working as you're trying to send the date as a `string` (e.g. `Wednesday, May 16, 2001`). Simply using `dat`, as opposed to `dat.ToLongDateString()` should work fine as it will be picked up by the database as a `DateTime` type

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I tried it by just keeping it as dat only. but still the same error

Comment: You can't keep it a date if you build the query as a string. You could if you used an `OleDbCommand` and `OleDbParameters`.

Comment: [Date is a reserved word.](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#D).  Enclose that name in square brackets ... `[DATE]` ... or rename the field to something which is not a reserved word.

Answer (score 3):

In Access, dates are delimited by `#`, not `'`. Also, Access does not recognize the long date format. But dates are not stored in any format so no worries, change it to:

```
... + "', #" + dat.ToString() + "# ...etc.
```

Although if you do not parameterize your query serious damage or data exposure can be done through SQL Injection because someone could type in a SQL statement into one of those textboxes that you are implicitly trusting.

Working example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder bldr = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
        bldr.DataSource = @"C:\Users\tekhe\Documents\Database2.mdb";
        bldr.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0";

        using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection cnxn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(bldr.ConnectionString))
        {
            cnxn.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("open");

            using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = cnxn;
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Dob]) VALUES(#" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "#)";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

[image]

> Update

However, you want to do something more like this which uses Parameters to protect against SQL Injection which is extremely easy to exploit so do not think that you don't really need to worry about it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    OleDbConnectionStringBuilder bldr = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
    bldr.DataSource = @"C:\Users\tekhe\Documents\Database2.mdb";
    bldr.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0";

    using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection cnxn = new OleDbConnection(bldr.ConnectionString))
    {
        cnxn.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("open");

        using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = cnxn;
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            OleDbParameter dobParam = new OleDbParameter("@dob", OleDbType.Date);
            dobParam.Value = DateTime.Now;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(dobParam);
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Dob]) VALUES(@dob)";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying.  i changed as you suggested. still the error remains same.

Comment: @NisargDongare, Could you show the error message in your question?

Comment: i have uploaded the image of error box .. see the link in question. thanks for rply

Comment: @NisargDongare, it may be that MS Access does not correctly parse the long date string format. Keep in mind that dates are not stored with a format, they are binary data on disk. When a date is read out of the database it can be formatted however you need. Try just `ToString()` and see if it works.

Comment: I used toString as well ... still problem didn't solved. Im unable to understand which date type i should keep in access.

Comment: im successful in reading out data from access in long format of date.... im using all the same settings still.. im unable to write the date in the access table

Comment: @NisargDongare, I just confirmed Access does not accept the long date format. See my sample code that works in a test database I just made.

Comment: sorry but im unable to understand your code. im new in c# .  can u please tell me the change in my code??

Comment: @NisargDongare, I already did. Instead of putting `'` around your date use `#`. If that isn't working then you have another problem. The code I have shown is confirmed working on my computer.

Comment: Hey thanks For your help :-)  I took that reference and made it ....!!  I realised the access database doesn't support for long format of date to insert but it accepts  to read the data .

Comment: this code worked :  command.CommandText = "insert into client_table(DATEE) values( '" dat.ToShortDateString()+"')";    i also changed the Date (Column name ) to Datee to get ride of exceptional things from access

Answer (score 0):

//code to write date in the access table.

```
string zero = "0";
DateTime dat = this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
//MessageBox.Show(dat.ToShortDateString());
connection1.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection1;
//command.CommandText = "insert into client_table(DATEE) values( '"dat.ToShortDateString()+"')";
command.CommandText = "insert into client_table (CLIENT, DATEE, BILL_AMOUNT, PAID_AMOUNT, BALANCE, CONTACT, ADDRESS )VALUES ('" + txt_client.Text + "', #"+dat.ToShortDateString()+"# ,'" + zero + "','" + zero + "','" + zero + "','" + txt_contact.Text + "','" + txt_address.Text + "')";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection1.Close();
MessageBox.Show("New Client Registration done Successfully.");
connection1.Dispose();
```

//New code  for receiving the date between two range of dates

```
try
  {
   DateTime dat = this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
   DateTime dat2 = this.dateTimePicker2.Value.Date;
   // MessageBox.Show(dat.ToShortDateString() + "  " + dat2.ToShortDateString());
   connection1.Open();
   OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
   command.Connection = connection1;
   string query;
   query = "select * from client_table Where DATEE Between #" + dat.ToLongDateString() +"# and #" + dat2.ToLongDateString() + "# ";
   command.CommandText = query;
   OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   da.Fill(dt);
   dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
   connection1.Close();
   }
 catch (Exception ex)
   {
     MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
   }
```

Thank you all of you for the support.